# GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT is not matching against User Locations Report

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I am working with the [GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report) in order to fetch data related to the account locations. More specifically, the report I am working with is the [User Locations Report](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7492954?hl=en), which can be found directly on the AdWords UI.

But I found out that there are some notorious differences for the data obtained via the AdWords API and the data shown via the AdWords UI, and the issues happen specifically with the aforementioned report, but also with the “*Geographic Report*”. I have applied the corresponding filters for the query, just as it's stated on the official documentation ([1](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report) and [2](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/uireports#user_locations_report)), but even with that, the data differs a lot between both sources.

The query I am constructing ends up being the following one:

```php
Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Query\v201809\ReportQuery {#7426
  -awqlString: "SELECT CampaignId, LocationType, Clicks, Impressions, CityCriteriaId, MostSpecificCriteriaId, CountryCriteriaId FROM GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE LocationType = 'LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE' AND IsTargetingLocation IN ['TRUE', 'FALSE'] DURING 20200401,20200430"
}
```

And the results I am getting (after sorting them by the `Clicks` metric) are the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xpme91ig6wu1oy/Screenshot%202020-05-13%2018.18.43.png?dl=0. But on the AdWords UI I get the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgtyglbs87lkb1p/Screenshot%202020-05-13%2018.20.20.png?dl=0.

I can see that there are similar issues open at the AdWords forum ([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/93kMXNbsi3I) and [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adwords-api/FDIdPVdSNRU/qz0RRuNSCAAJ)), but none of them seem fully solved.

Finally, based in the https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting documentation and in some other tests I did by using the `MostSpecificCriteriaId`, I have the theory that this could be an issue with the zipcodes mapping on the API.

Do you know what is the reason of the discrepancy for the click counts (and also for the impression counts) between both sources of these report?. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was resolved on the same thread we posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/PlJGl7iPVBc.

After some back and forth with the AdWords API support, it turned out to be a data issue from their side, which is now fixed according to them. I double checked from my side and I could successfully confirm that the data is now correct and that there is no mismatch.